# Cloning a JS element that contains a chained select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a script to clone a div, which works fine, however but the javascript chained function within it no longer works for any cloned elements. Works ok for the first one as expected.

I've created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bvcebmbw/

The javascript is as follows (for both chained and clone functions)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Targeting").each(function () {

            $('#TargetingAdd').click(function () {

                var num = $('.clonedTargeting').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                    newNum = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
                    newElem = $('#entryTargeting' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entryTargeting' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

                // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
                $('#entryTargeting' + num).after(newElem);

                // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
                $('#TargetingDel').attr('disabled', false);

                init(newElem.children(".Targeting"));

                // Right now you can only add 4 sections, for a total of 5. Change '5' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#TargetingAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached


            });

            $('#TargetingDel').click(function () {
                // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
                if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this Targeting?")) {
                    var num = $('.clonedTargeting').length;
                    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                    $('#entryTargeting' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                        if (num - 1 === 1)
                            $('#TargetingDel').attr('disabled', true);
                        // enable the "add" button
                        $('#TargetingAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");
                    });
                }
                return false; // Removes the last section you added
            });
        });
        // Enable the "add" button
        $('#TargetingAdd').attr('disabled', false);
        // Disable the "remove" button
        $('#TargetingDel').attr('disabled', true);
    });
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
"use strict";

$.fn.chained = function(parent_selector, options) {

    return this.each(function() {

        /* Save this to child because this changes when scope changes. */
        var child   = this;
        var backup = $(child).clone();

        /* Handles maximum two parents now. */
        $(parent_selector).each(function() {
            $(this).bind("change", function() {
                updateChildren();
            });

            /* Force IE to see something selected on first page load, */
            /* unless something is already selected */
            if (!$("option:selected", this).length) {
                $("option", this).first().attr("selected", "selected");
            }

            /* Force updating the children. */
            updateChildren();
        });

        function updateChildren() {
            var trigger_change = true;
            var currently_selected_value = $("option:selected", child).val();

            $(child).html(backup.html());

            /* If multiple parents build classname like foo\bar. */
            var selected = "";
            $(parent_selector).each(function() {
                var selectedClass = $("option:selected", this).val();
                if (selectedClass) {
                    if (selected.length > 0) {
                        if (window.Zepto) {
                            /* Zepto class regexp dies with classes like foo\bar. */
                            selected += "\\\\";
                        } else {
                            selected += "\\";
                        }
                    }
                    selected += selectedClass;
                }
            });

            /* Also check for first parent without subclassing. */
            /* TODO: This should be dynamic and check for each parent */
            /*       without subclassing. */
            var first;
            if ($.isArray(parent_selector)) {
                first = $(parent_selector[0]).first();
            } else {
                first = $(parent_selector).first();
            }
            var selected_first = $("option:selected", first).val();

            $("option", child).each(function() {
                /* Remove unneeded items but save the default value. */
                if ($(this).hasClass(selected) && $(this).val() === currently_selected_value) {
                    $(this).prop("selected", true);
                    trigger_change = false;
                } else if (!$(this).hasClass(selected) && !$(this).hasClass(selected_first) && $(this).val() !== "") {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

            /* If we have only the default value disable select. */
            if (1 === $("option", child).size() && $(child).val() === "") {
                $(child).prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(child).prop("disabled", false);
            }
            if (trigger_change) {
                $(child).trigger("change");
            }
        }
    });
};

/* Alias for those who like to use more English like syntax. */
$.fn.chainedTo = $.fn.chained;

/* Default settings for plugin. */
$.fn.chained.defaults = {};

})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto, window, document);


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#connectionSub").chained("#connectionType");
$("#apppagesoptions").chained("#connectionSub");

$("#phoneVersion").chained("#phoneBrand");

$("#osVersionMin").chained("#phoneVersion");
$("#osVersionMax").chained("#phoneVersion");



});
```

and the HTML is 3 chained  inputs:

```
<div class="Targeting">
        <select id="connectionType" name="connectionType[]">
            <option disabled value="">--</option>
            <option value="pages">Facebook Pages</option>
            <option value="apps">Apps</option>
            <option disabled value="">--</option>
            <option value="advanced">Advanced Connections</option>
        </select>
        <select id="connectionSub" name="connectionSub[]">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="page_like" class="pages">People who like your Page</option>
            <option value="page_friend" class="pages">Friends of people who like your Page</option>
            <option value="page_exclude" class="pages">Exclude people who like your Page</option>

            <option value="app_like" class="apps">People who like your App</option>
            <option value="app_friend" class="apps">Friends of people who like your App</option>
            <option value="app_exclude" class="apps">Exclude people who like your App</option>

        </select>




        <select id="apppagesoptions" name="apppagesoptions[]" multiple>
            <option>test</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div><!-- end #entry1 -->
<div id="addDelButtons">
    <input type="button" id="TargetingAdd" value="add section">
    <input type="button" id="TargetingDel" value="remove section above">
</div>
```

Appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

For all the `<div class="Targeting">` the `select` element's ids are remain same. that's why it's only working for first one.

Comment: But I require the ID to be the same for the chained function to work

Comment: @tomantford Can't it changed to class? will look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: So to include class="targeting" and id="targeting_1 ..2..3 etc?

Comment: @tomantford you could use dynamic ids like you mention previous comment.